# Proving that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{k!}$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to prove that  $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k]{k!}$ diverges. I've rewritten this as $$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \exp\left(\frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^k \log(n)\right)
$$
which diverges if $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^k \log(n)$ diverges

It is here that I am having trouble. I apply the ratio test and examine the limit $$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|
\frac{\log(k+1)/(k+1)}{\log(k)/k}
\right|=
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left|\frac{\log(k+1)}{\log k}\right|
\left|\frac{k}{k+1}\right|.
$$

Letting $$
a_k = \left|\frac{\log(k+1)}{\log k}\right|
~~\text{ and }~~
b_k = \left|\frac{k}{k+1}\right|,$$ it seems that $a_k$ is greater than 1.0 by an amount which is less than the amount by which $b_k$ is less than 1.

Therefore, it should be the case that $$
0 < \lim_{k\to\infty} a_k b_k < 1
$$
which by the ratio tests would imply that the sum $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{n=1}^k \log(n)$ converges.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: To answer your question of "Where am I going wrong," the limit of $a_kb_k$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: @Bernard: thanks, Stirling's formula does the trick.

Comment: @Cheerful Parsnip: good point, I missed this. So in this case the ratio test would be inconclusive.

Comment: @ted: that's right.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "it seems that $a_k$ is greater than 1.0 by an amount which is less than the amount by which $b_k$ is less than 1"

**This** is where you are going wrong. Regardless of whether this somewhat hazy statement is true (for some notion of "amount", etc.), the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test) does not care about these considerations. Both quantities go to 1: thus the ratio goes to 1. A limit of 1 for the ratio leads to an **inconclusive** ratio test.

Therefore, you need to use a different, or more fine-grained approach: you cannot conclude by the ratio test.

---

*As discussed in the comments, you may want to use [refinements of the ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Extensions_for_L_=_1) to try and conclude with this type of argument. Raabe's test (first refinement: look at $\lim_{k\to\infty} k(\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}-1)$) will still be inconclusive, but Bertrand's test (stronger refinement: look at $\lim_{k\to\infty} \left(k\log k (\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}-1) - \log k\right)$) will let you establish the result.*

Comment: For what it's worth, by the way, your hazy statement *is* true: the ratio behaves like $$1-1/k + o(1/k)$$ as $k\to\infty$. But this still leads to an inconclusive ratio test (and Raabe's test as well, for that matter). (**But** Bertrand's test, a finer extension, would allow you to conclude)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $k!\ge (k/2)^{k/2}$ for large $k.$

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't actually answer the question {"Where am I going wrong?")

Answer (score 2):

Let $L=\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \sqrt[k] k!$.We have $\ln L=\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \ln \sqrt[k] k!=\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln k!}{k} $.
By Stolz-Cesaro's Lemma,$\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln k!}{k}=\lim \limits_{k \to \infty}\ln(k+1) =\infty$,so $L=\infty$.